# Assembly binding error when building Office add-in: "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, jenkins

We're trying to set up a Jenkins (build server) job to build our Office add-in based on VSTO. However, I keep getting a strange error that fails the build process after the DLL is copied to the `bin` directory of the project:

```
Error 11 The "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
  Could not load file or assembly 'MyAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
  The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MyAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

So the problem is that the "FindRibbons" task, triggered by the Office add-in build target, has successfully identified the MyAddIn DLL as being an Office Add-In, but is not able to locate and load it!

Any ideas? I'd love to be able to debug the FindRibbons task directly but hooking into and debugging the compile process seems a little extreme...

---

Here are some observations:

- In our build server's Fusion logs for binding the MyAddIn assembly it looks like it's looking in the folder where MSBuild.exe lives (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`) and nowhere else.
  On my dev machine, there is no Fusion log entry for MyAddIn! But the build process succeeds and Kivo works fine.
- On both my dev and build machines I also have Fusion log entries for `WhereRefBind!Host=(LocalMachine)!FileName=(PresentationCore.dll)` and `ExplicitBind!FileName=(MyAddIn.dll)` which show the binding succeeding.
- This error comes up on the build server whether I use Visual Studio or MSBuild from the command line to build the project.
- I've ensured that the .NET/MSBuild/VS2012 versions are identical on both my dev machine and the build server and the error still occurs. The only difference seems to be that the build server is running Windows Server 2012 (since it's Azure, and we can't spin up a Windows 7 image).

Comment: Try this - https://13.64.155.221/comments/574521/view.html

Answer (score 9):

This has worked for me every time I upgrade Visual Studio - I don't use ribbons.

This worked for my solution, but use at your own risk:

1. Open the following file in an XML editor (make a backup first): `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets` (the v10.0 part may be different for you, e.g., it might be v14.0)
2. Remove the following section:

   ```
   <FindRibbons AssemblyName="$(AbsolutePathToCustomization)" TargetFramework="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)">
       <Output TaskParameter="RibbonTypes" ItemName="RibbonTypesCollection"/>
   </FindRibbons>
   ```
3. Replace all occurrences of `"@(RibbonTypesCollection)"` with the empty string `""`
4. Save the file and restart the visual studio

Comment: This still appears to be a bug 3 years later!

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(349,5): error : Failed to add the customization.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem. It was apparently caused because I changed the "Copy Local" setting on reference "Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities" from True to False. ISYN. (I sh*t you not)

I had upgraded a project from VS2012 to VS2013 and noticed that that reference was the only one set to "Copy Local = True". So I set it to false, because it was different. This caused the error. Changing it back to True solved it.

Comment: Excuse me. This is not the text I wrote. WTF is up with someone "editing" my comment?

Comment: Almost anyone can edit a post to make it more clear or fix errors. The history is preserved and it can be reverted if malicious.

Comment: I am having the same issue when I set CopyLocal = False. I don't want to have a local copy of the assembly so what can I do?

Answer (score 8):

If you migrated the project from a previous version of Visual Studio, be sure to remove the **ExcelLocale1033** and **SecurityTransparent** attributes from the AssemblyInfo.cs file (as answered by Swati in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25376700/1905436))

If the project still fails to build, it may be because your .csproj file has some references to msbuild's tasks of previous versions of Visual Studio. I suggest you to create a new empty Excel AddIn project, and uses the msbuild structure of the new project file as base for your project.

Comment: Yes, I migrated from VS 2010 to VS 2012.
Removing "SecurityTransparent " helped, thanks!

Comment: This was my issue as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error message and finally found a fix. The problem stemmed from the VSTO project being targeted for .NET 4.0 (it seems this is the minimum for VSTO4), while also referencing an assembly built for .NET 3.5. The real culprit was that I had a class in the VSTO project deriving from an interface defined in the .NET 3.5 assembly that in turn derived from a .NET 3.5 library interface. i.e.,

```
   using System.Xml;
   class MyVSTOClass : IMy35AssembyInterface // This caused the error
   class MyVSTOClass : IXmlSerializable      // This compiled OK 

   using System.Xml;
   interface IMy35AssembyInterface : IXmlSerializable
```

The fix was to update the .csproj to explicitly reference the older version of System.Xml.dll and System.Data.dll which would otherwise default to 4.0 and conflict with the 3.5 assembly references.

```
  <Reference Include="System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <!--<Aliases>Data2</Aliases>-->
      <HintPath>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll</HintPath>
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>

 <Reference Include="System.XML, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <!--<Aliases>Xml2</Aliases>-->
      <HintPath>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll</HintPath>
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
```

For those who need to simultaneously reference both the newer and older versions of a DLL, note that it is in theory possible using:

```
extern alias XmlDll1
using XmlDll1::System.Xml
```

See http://geekswithblogs.net/narent/archive/2008/11/11/126940.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 5):

This problem can also be caused by adding a reference to an unsigned assembly to a signed/strong named add-in project.  In my case I added the RestSharp Nuget package and started receiving this error on build as soon as I referenced RestSharp in code.  After some digging I noticed that RestSharp was the only unsigned assembly in the project references.  If you have this problem, there are 3 possible solutions:

1. In the case of RestSharp, I found that there was a signed version available on Nuget - searched for "restsharp signed" and installing that solved the problem.
2. If you have access to the source code, you can configure Visual Studio to build a signed version of the assembly in the Project Properties page.
3. If you do not have access to the source code, you can sign the assembly with your own key by following [these instructions](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2010/04/23/sign-a-.net-assembly-with-a-strong-name-without-recompiling.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and none of the answers from the internet help me fix this problem. The reason why I was getting that error is because I was referencing an assembly of type `Console Application`. I changed that assembly to be of type ClassLibrary and I did not got that exception any more.

Also I would only get that exception when inheriting from a class that was located on my ConsoleApplication. It took me forever to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

May be a little late here, but I just resolved this for myself - after following numerous suggestions (via google) all of which did not solve my problem I manually went down the line.  Turns out I had compiled a set of libraries with a dependent assembly with a lower version (not the latest). In my main project I also had a reference to this dependency but it was pulled via nuget and was at the latest & greatest version.  For some reason VS.NET couldn't figure that out and would completely trip out and drop the error you posted. Once I updated the set of libraries to the latest version of the dependency all worked as normal.

The crazy part is - it worked fine initially and then out of nowhere the issue came about. Hope this helps someone along the way.

After enabling Fusion the output showed that it was looking for the assembly in the msbuild/ folder.

Comment: yep, updating all my packages using nuget update-package resolved this error for me. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same situation today, futzing around for a bit, restarting VS and then rebooting my machine without any success. Than one warning popped out at me - One of my dependent assemblies was not strong named. Setting that assembly to be strong-named solved the problem.

Comment: Checked `Sign Assembly` in my project and got the error above. Found the dll without strong name. Got the source signed/compiled/referenced it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and even after reading KKG's answer I could not resolve mine.

It turned out to be much simpler for me, but not less frustrating and time consuming.  I was working in a Win8.1 VM which does not ship with .net3.5 by default.  My .net4 VSTO4 project was referencing an assembly that requires 3.5 somewhere.  The same project compiled find on my other VM which was Server2008 and had 3.5 enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause for this error was the mere existence of a field of a generic value type in the assembly (not kidding), e.g.:

```
  class Foo
  {
    ImmutableArray<int> foo;
  }
```

Workaround (if the additional indirection is acceptable performance-wise):

Wrap the value type in a reference type. This can be done generically with something like

```
  public sealed class Box<T>
  {
    public readonly T value;

    public Box(T value)
    {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
```

then `foo` can be of type `Box<ImmutableArray<int>>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this same issue with an add-in for Outlook.

The solution for me was to set `Embed Interop Types` to `True` on my reference to `Office.dll`.

This however caused the add-in to crash during startup with an `Access Denied` on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. I fixed that issue by setting `Embed Interop Types` to `True` on all references to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by a clash of dependency versions. For example:

```
YourAddIn
  --  OtherLibrary v1.3
      --  BaseLibrary v1.0
  --  BaseLibrary v2.0
```

If a newer version of `BaseLibrary` v2.0 is released and updated in your project, however this version introduce a breaking change in your other dependency `OtherLibrary`, you will see this exception because `OtherLibrary` is still trying to find the old methods that doesn't exist in newer assembly.

Update `OtherLibrary` with the latest packages will resolve this clash of dependency versions.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v4.0.Utilities` reference is set to `<Private>False</Private>`.

```xml
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v4.0.Utilities">
  <!-- Required for FindRibbons task -->
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```