# Build error of Excel VSTO project, "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly.System.ArgumentException: Invalid directory on URL in VS 2013

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio-2013, vsto

I am trying to convert VS2010 (C# .net 4.0) projects into VS2013. In the solution, there are 6 projects totally including MyApp.Excel, MyApp.Host, MyApp.WCF, MyApp.Web, SetupAction, MyAppSetup.

MyApp.Excel  is an EXCEL VSTO project.  It was originally designed for Excel 2003. **Do I need to do something to make it support Excel 2010? Before conversion,   the Excel add-in of the application can be opened in Excel 2010 well.**

MyAppSetup is a MSI installer project. I have installed VS installer projects extensions from

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx

Now, I can build all projects in VS2013 except MyApp.Excel and MyAppSetup. The latter one depends in the first one.

In MyApp.Excel, I got build error:

```
 Error 11   The "FindRibbons" task failed    unexpectedly.System.ArgumentException: Invalid directory on URL.
```

Server stack trace:

```
at System.Security.Util.DirectoryString.CreateSeparatedString(String directory)
at System.Security.Util.URLString.ParseFileURL(String url)
at System.Security.Util.URLString.ParseString(String url, Boolean parsed)
at System.Security.Util.URLString.GetFileName()
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.FindRibbons.FindRibbonTypes(String assemblyName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.FindRibbons.Execute()
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& m sgData, Int32 type)
at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
at  Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() MyApp.Excel
```

**I have searched/tried many related solutions but none of following them worked for me.**

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5831d519-ba81-413a-9936-efe0ff328348/vsto-project-fails-to-build-i-get-the-following-error-msb4018-the-find-ribbons-task-failed?forum=vsto

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c86f8d52-7c33-41a6-b37f-593a218858ce/findribbons-task-failed-unexpectedly?forum=vsto

[Assembly binding error when building Office add-in: "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220031/assembly-binding-error-when-building-office-add-in-findribbons-task-failed-un)

[FindRibbons task failed unexpectedly when building addin for Outlook 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505938/findribbons-task-failed-unexpectedly-when-building-addin-for-outlook-2010)

http://www.wpthm.com/t/ibs13h11mmvs6v799stssrkbskvri39s

What does the error mean? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you migrated the project from a previous version of Visual Studio, be sure to remove the **ExcelLocale1033** and **SecurityTransparent** attributes from the AssemblyInfo.cs file.
Because there properties are internally handled by .Net framework 4 and above .