# C# compilation issue - The "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, winforms, compilation

I am developing the outlook add-ins using the winform in c#. Its working smoothly until last friday. But certainly my code not getting compiled. Its throw the below error message. But myself did not make any changes in my code.

**

```
Error   45  The "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'testAddin, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'testAddin, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
    testAddin
```

**

Please give me suggestion to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: DId you change your version of visual studio or outlook?

Comment: No Dave, I did not make any changes in my environment. Its happened suddenly, Say for example I have compiled "After noon 1'o clock, that compilation getting success. Suddenly my visual studio automatically getting closed. So, Myself re-open the visual studio and try to compile again. But now  the process getting failed. So dint have any clue about this.

Comment: I would close Visual Studio, Outlook, and  do a hard reset of your PC and try to compile again.  If you have the same problem, think hard, something must have changed.

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried one  by one. First uninstall and install the visual studio and check whether the compilation is working or not. Then uninstall and install the outlook, But both time the compilation wont get success. Finally reset the PC to compile the code. Unfortunately i did not found the root cause of the issue. :( . Any way thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi  Ramachandran. By any chance do you have another computer that you can try?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with other computer as well. I did not face this issue with other computer.

Comment: Great.  If you have another PC where everything works.  You need to carefully check the differences between the two.  There has to be something different. Debug your application step by step on both computers until you find the point where things differ.  Hopefully that will provide a clue.  From your error, you need to focus on your addin, make sure all versions are the same as well as each dependency -  for instance start here 'testAddin, Version=1.0.0.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly binding error when building Office add-in: "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220031/assembly-binding-error-when-building-office-add-in-findribbons-task-failed-un)